# How to manage customer 'log-in' in Silverlight ?

Tags: silverlight

I wrote a web application in Silverlight and in some places the user need to log-in.

When the user logs-in I check the username + password (if it exists in the database) and simply give the permission to the user account.

Questions:

1. Is there some class / framework that I can use to make this 'log-in' more easy to develop?
2. How can I enable the 'Stay signed in' option in the log-in?

Comment: No,  i'm not using RIA services.

Comment: Are you able to?  RIA Services would answer question #1.  Also, what version of Silverlight are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee942449%28v=vs.91%29.aspx) is a walkthrough of using Authentication Service with Silverlight Business Application.  It's a good place to start.

It's fairly flexible and easy to work with.  The example in the Business Application inherits from `AuthenticaitonBase<>` you can override Login, Logout, GetUser, and UpdateUser.

> How can I enable the 'Stay signed in' option in the log-in?

If you're using FormsAuthentication, in your Login method:

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(userName, true);
```

Answer (score 1):

When combining WCF and Silverlight you'll need to protect the services from unauthorized calls. [Following this post should get you up and running](http://www.ben-morris.com/securing-wcf-web-services-for-silverlight-with-forms-authentication)